# Categorical Variable in EditMetadata module of Azure ML

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

Could anyone please let me know what is the purpose of making some variable as Categorical in EditMetadata module of Machine Learning? Would appreciate if explained with some example. Also is it applicable on both features as well as label?

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where variables are considered as string instead of categorical. This impacts the accuracy of the model based on how variable is treated. So for these cases, user may want to have system treat these variables categorical instead of string and edit meta-data module helps in enforcing this behavior

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/370b6676-c11c-486f-bf73-35349f842a66?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks Neeraj. Could you please elaborate it with an example that how categorical and non-categorical variables affect the accuracy of model. I am new to Machine Learning.